# Export formatting of an Excel worksheet to Powershell (or VBA) commands

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

There are several threads here on SO which are concerned with filling and formatting an Excel sheet out of Powershell. The concepts for this are easy, but creating a report in this way can quickly become cumbersome -- particularly when a nice format is desired.

Therefore, I want to get rid of the whole formatting and instead base the report on an existing template, for example looking like

[image]

The fields A2, B2 and C2 then shall be filled through a Powershell script.

The straightforward way to accomplish this would be to create the Excel template once and save it somewhere as a file. Then let the script open the template, fill it with data, and save it somewhere else. Although this works, it is not nice as the powershell script is not self-contained: one always needs to handle two files, the script as well as the template.

Therefore, I'm seeking for a way to bundle together the script and the Excel template. My first idea for this is to export the Excel template as a series of formatting commands. (This is similar to the result of a macro, where one obtains VBA code, but a macro is not maintainable: if I want to add one column, I'd need to repeat the whole macro.)

Ideally, with this I would like to have the example sheet exported into Powershell like

```
$sheet.cells.item(1,1) = 'Name'
$sheet.cells.item(1,1).font.Name = 'Calibri'
$sheet.cells.item(1,1).font.bold = $True
... and so on ...
```

(As said, Powershell would be optimal, but I could also arrange with VBA, why I tagged it as well.)

**Is it possible to create such an export?**

Comment: Have you thought about having the script open an pre-formatted Excel Template (XLTX), instead of creating a new file which is blank and un-formatted?

Comment: http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSExcel-Intro/ , https://learn-powershell.net/2012/12/20/powershell-and-excel-adding-some-formatting-to-your-report/